# How should I visualize mappings in topology?

Tags: general-topology

When I'm trying to visualize mappings from one topological space to another, say from (X,T) to (Y,T1), should I be thinking of the elements X being mapped to elements Y or should I be thinking in terms of open sets in T mapped to open sets in T1?

Comment: Both...........

Comment: If we talk about continuous mappings $X\to Y$, i think of them mostly as embeddings of $X$ into $Y$, but this is just me. It also depends on the given context and i adapt according to the topic.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No, the second one doesn't make sense: not all continuous maps are open. It should be the other way around.

Comment: I don't see why you can't think of both mapping of *elements* and mapping of *open sets*, assuming (as the OP apparently does) that the spaces *have* open sets.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Because a continuous function between topological spaces doesn't induce a function from the set of open subsets of the initial space to the set of open subsets of the target space, but rather the other way around.

Comment: @Zest I think it's dangerous to think of general continuous maps as embeddings - they might not be one-to-one, and even if they are they could still be messy (e.g. a continuous bijection which is not a homeomorphism).

Comment: i know, embedding was just the term that was closest to what i meant, maybe i should have said "singular embedding", s.t. the image of X can look messy inside Y. still appreciating your comment though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map itself goes from $X$ to $Y$, and that's how you should visualize it.

A good example of this that you can draw for yourself is the notion of a **path** in topology. Intuitively, if I have a topological space $(Y,\sigma)$, a path in $Y$ should be a way of "drawing a line" in $Y$ in a continuous way. This winds up being best phrased as **a continuous map from $[0,1]$ with the usual topology**. (There's a bit of a subtlety here; what we think of colloquially as a path is really *the image of* such a map, but the term "path" winds up being used for the map itself because that's ultimately a more useful thing to consider.

---

That said, what $f$ does to sets is very important ... but you want to look *backwards*! Specifically, if $f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\sigma)$ is a continuous function (= the right kind of map to consider when doing topology), we have $$f^{-1}(U)\in\tau\mbox{ whenever }U\in\sigma.$$ The original $f$ was, set-theoretically, a function from $X$ to $Y$, but it induces a function $\hat{f}:\sigma\rightarrow\tau$.

By contrast, continuous maps **need not** send open sets to open sets. Consider for example $$f: (\mathbb{R}, \tau_{Euc,1})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^2, \tau_{Euc,2}): x\mapsto (x,0).$$ (Here $\tau_{Euc, n}$ is the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.) This is continuous but does not send open sets to open sets.